# Is Firefox hang caused by disk slows?

Tags: hard-drive, firefox, freeze

I have a lot of users running Firefox on Remote Desktop Servers.

The server resources of CPU and RAM are very light - definitely no problem and running at 20% capacity.

However, a few times a minute, Firefox will freeze / hang / not respond for a few seconds, and then start responding again.

I know I currently have a problem with disk IO, as hundreds of user profiles across multiple servers are stored in one central location and this drive is overloaded, especially on writes. I am mid handling this with a whole new storage infrastructure.

I suspect Firefox is trying to write temporary files, and so hangs there. I would like to confirm this.

Theoretically in this case, if I disable the ability for a user to cache files, this hang should go away.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: There are hundreds of programs that will benchmark this type of activity for you. You can use those results to determine if your problem is caused by disk I/O problems or some other reason.

Comment: True. All I am asking, is it is a regular symptom in firefox to hang if it is trying to write to a disk?

Comment: Its a regular symptom for any process with high I/O delays.  Have you performed a benchmark on the Firefox process to verify there high I/O delays?